# testflight запрошенное приложение недоступно или не существует

Tags: ios, xcode

Собираю приложение но в testflight не собирается появляется ошибка

> запрошенное приложение недоступно или не существует

через XCODE собирается без проблем

- версию обновлял
- git до предыдущей версии откатывал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается это признак что аккаунт скоро удалят.